# Rederização condicional de um componente a partir de um item selecionado

Tags: react, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

boa tarde, estou passando por dificuldades a realizar uma renderização condicional que tem como objetivo renderizar um IconButton somente quando e selecionado um valor da lista predefinida.

minha const com a lista

```
const [nomesRepresentantes, setNomesRepresentantes] = useState<
    { id: number; title: string }[]
  >([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setNomesRepresentantes([
      { id: 1, title: "João da silva" },
      { id: 2, title: "Joãozinho da silva" },
      { id: 3, title: "Maria da silva" },
      { id: 4, title: "José da silva" },
    ]);
  }, []);
```

aqui está meu autocomplete aonde seleciono os nomes

```
<Autocomplete
   id="namesAutocomplete"
   options={names.map((option) => option.title)}
   freeSolo
   value={representante.representante}
   renderInput={(params) => (
   <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" />
   )}
/>
```

e este e o IconButton que preciso renderizar somente quando seleciono um valor do meu Autocomplete a cima

```
<IconButton>
  <OpenInNewSharpIcon
    fontSize="default"
    color="primary"
  />
</IconButton>
```

caso seja necessário posso compartilhar todo o meu componente, agradeço antecipadamente a ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que está na documentação diz que no evento `onChange` é o responsável pela mudança de estado de alguma variável previamente configurado no seu componente [Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/pt/components/autocomplete/). Isso já acontece no componente natural do [html](/questions/tagged/html) com o nome de `select`, então o exemplo dado na documentação é o seguinte:

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);
<Autocomplete
    value={value}
    onChange={(event, newValue) => {
      setValue(newValue);
    }}
```

no momento dessa alteração configure um `React.useEffect` para monitorar as modificações na variável de estado `value` para que possa alterar algum componente na tela, observe:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    //efeito observado quando a variavel `value` for alterada
}, [value])
```

ou então utilizando a própria variável `value` ao alterar o estado escrever da seguinte forma:

```
{value != null && (
    <IconButton>
      <OpenInNewSharpIcon
        fontSize="default"
        color="primary"
     />
    </IconButton>
)}
```

se a variável for diferente de `null` mostre o componente `<IconButton>`.

Um exemplo real com componente basicos [html](/questions/tagged/html):

```js
function Main() {
  const [options, setOptions] = React.useState(['Sim', 'Não']);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(options[1]);  
  return (
    <div style={{padding: 10}}>
     <div style={{height: 30}}>
     {value === 'Sim' && (<span>Mostrando ...</span>)}
     </div>
     <div>
      <select value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}>
       { options.map((o,i) => (<option>{o}</option>) ) }
      </select>
     </div>     
    </div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render( <Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

nesse exemplo demonstra que dependendo do valor, mostra uma mensagem, e isso é um exemplo claro que tu pode utilizar no seu projeto.

[No próprio site tem um exemplo](https://material-ui.com/pt/components/autocomplete/#controllable-states) leia que também vai te ajudar muito.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda amigo!